# How to fix problem of mixed content https & http with angular and ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: asp.net, angular, reverse-proxy, netlify, mixed-content

I have deployed my backend app made with ASP.NET Core Web API to Smarter Asp and my API is at `http://smartapi.com/.....` .

I have deployed my frontend app written in Angular to Netlify and my site is: `https://astonishing-speculoos-d0b898.netlify.app/`

Now, I have a problem that netlify doesn't accept requests with http in its website. How to fix this problem to make my API backend requests work in netlify website?

Comment: Well - use just **`https://`** for your API endpoints.....

Comment: no , Smarter asp generate http api only ... change it to https make the api unkown in browser

Comment: you must buy ssl to get https domain for your apis

Comment: So then - find some other hoster that **does support** `https://` ??

Comment: @AZZOUNIMOHAMEDAMIR I believe that you need to setup SSL on your site first so you can use https. You can ask their support. Some of providers offer free SSL, for example I'm using Asphostportal and they fully support for Let's Encrypt.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at SmarterAsp's website, it actually seems to be possible to get a free Let's Encrypt certificate.

Link:
https://www.smarterasp.net/free_lets_encrypt_ssl_hosting

When you've added the Let's Encrypt to your hosting plan, you should go ahead and change the URL's for your API calls to include "https://" rather than "http://"